# update order by clause ordering differently then select order by

Tags: mysql

I have a `UPDATE` query with an `ORDER BY` clause. I have copied the same query to a `SELECT` with the same `ORDER BY` clause and I'm getting different results.

**Update Query:**

```
UPDATE t_locks
SET server_guid = 11028790,
lock_time_to_live = TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,5,NOW())
WHERE
(server_guid IS NULL OR NOW() > lock_time_to_live OR lock_time_to_live IS NULL)
AND lock_key_id = 3
ORDER BY flag DESC, last_time_processed ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

**Select Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM t_locks
WHERE
(server_guid IS NULL OR NOW() > lock_time_to_live OR lock_time_to_live IS NULL)
AND lock_key_id = 3
ORDER BY flag DESC, last_time_processed ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Note: I am not checking the results of the `UPDATE` with this `SELECT`.

Suspicion: In addition to the normal `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` query it is adding a 3rd parameter which is `ID`. I would expect the `UPDATE` to do the same thing.

Comment: Check if there are any trigger actions defined on `t_locks`?

Comment: @Ravinder There are none.

Answer (score 0):

SQL databases do not add anything to the `order by`.  For good reason, SQL does not implement a stable sort.  The good reason is that tables represent unordered sets, so there is no baseline for the sort order.  If you order by a constant, you are not guaranteed to get the same order two times in a row.  Ties can appear in any order.  And they do.

What you have just learned is that you have duplicates based on `flag` and `last_time_processed`.  It is unclear from your question whether you have 11 or more with the same values, or just two that are at positions 10 and 11 for the `select` but 11 and 10 for the `update`.

It turns out that SQL Server [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) does a better job of explaining this (in the context of paging) than MySQL:

> To achieve stable results between query requests  . . . the following conditions must be met:
>
> . . .
>
> 1. The ORDER BY clause contains a column or combination of columns that are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: I have 100-200 rows with the same values. My `select` is consistent with its results and the same with the `update`. If I manually an additional `ORDER BY id ASC` in my `UPDATE` query the results match.

Comment: @BrainPicker . . . Then add the `id` to the `order by` for both queries.  There is no guarantee on the ordering for keys that match.

Comment: The `ORDER BY id` isn't something important to me. I was inquiring as to why the `select` has consistent but different results than the `update`.